# Parcelable data returning null

Tags: android

I have the following three classes.

**Cricketers**

```
 public class Cricketers implements Parcelable {

        private String name;
        private String address;
        private int age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }


        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public Cricketers() {
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flag) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(address);
            dest.writeInt(age);
        }

        public Cricketers(Parcel in) {
            this.name = in.readString();
            this.address = in.readString();
            this.age = in.readInt();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public Cricketers createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Cricketers(in);
            }

            public Cricketers[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Cricketers[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

**Activity1**

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Cricketers> cricketers;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cricketers = new ArrayList<Cricketers>();

        Cricketers object = new Cricketers();
        object.setName("Sachin");
        object.setAddress("Mumbai");
        object.setAge(37);
        cricketers.add(object);

        Cricketers object1 = new Cricketers();
        object1.setName("Sourav");
        object1.setAddress("Kolkata");
        object1.setAge(38);
        cricketers.add(object1);

        Cricketers object2 = new Cricketers();
        object2.setName("Dravid");
        object2.setAddress("Bengaluru");
        object2.setAge(38);
        cricketers.add(object2);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("cricketers", cricketers);
        startActivity(intent);

        cricketers = null;

    }
```

**Activity2**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Cricketers cricketers = bundle.getParcelable("cricketers");

    }

}
```

I am retrieving the data on Activity2 , but its returning cricketers = null .

Within the Activity1 class , the data "cricketers" is being properly added to the Intent.

Kindly provide your inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue ....

Changes need to done to the **Activity2** class

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<Cricketers> data = new ArrayList<Cricketers>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        data = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("cricketers");

        for (int count = 0; count < data.size(); count++) {

            Cricketers cric = (Cricketers) data.get(count);
            String name = cric.getName();
            String address = cric.getAddress();
            int age = cric.getAge();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some problem with AIDL cache ... if you change all your code abour the parcelable, or simple you refactor the name of the class. if you reinstall the app, or clear the app cache, the AIDL is still working and searching fot that refactored class.

I fix this task rebooting the device. It a crap to change code in the parcelable class but not see it works when reinstall the app, you MUST to reboot the device... or thats whar I do.

Thanks for the example dude ;) the activit2 was a bless!!